# Will isset() trigger __get and why?

Tags: php, isset

```
class a {
   function __get($property){...}
}

$obj = new a();
var_dump(isset($obj->newproperty));
```

Seems the answer is nope but why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it checks [__isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) rather than retrieving it using __get.

It is a much better option to call __isset, as there is no standard on what is empty. Maybe in the context of the class null is an acceptable value. You could also have a class that if the member didn't exist, it returned a new empty object, which would break `isset($myObj->item)` as in that case it would always return true.

Answer (score 2):

It just isn't; you can use __isset instead. This is laid out [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Answer (score 1):

No, `__get` should not be triggered when you're trying to determine whether a property is set : testing if a property is set is not the same thing as trying to get its value.

Using `isset` triggers the `__isset` magic method.

See :

- [`isset`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
- and [Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Comment: Seems I didn't define __isset in my example?

Comment: Seems you didn't, indeed -- but, if you had defined it, it should have been called ;; and defining it or not doesn't change anything about `__get` not being called when you're testing if a property is set.

Answer (score 0):

The magic function __get is only called when you try to access a property that doesn't exist. Checking whether a property exists is not the same as retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A{
   public function __get($key){
      ...
   }
   public function __set($key,$name){
      ...
   }
   public function __unset($key){
      ...
   }
   public function __isset($key){
      ...
   }
}
$obj = new A();
$get = $obj->newproperty;//$obj->__get("newproperty")
$obj->newproperty = "X";//$obj->__set("newproperty","X")
$bool = isset($obj->newproperty);//$obj->__isset("newproperty")
unset($obj->newproperty);//$obj->__unset("newproperty")
```