# isset Seems to Return a Wrong Value

Tags: php

I have currently been trying to separate my PHP and HTML. I am trying to only use inline PHP in my HTML files. Sometimes I will want to check if a variable in the array is set before I `echo` it.

Here is a small test of the problem:

```
<?
class test
{
    private $args;
    public function __construct($args = array())
    {
        $this->args = $args;
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->args[$name];
    }
    function test_i()
    {
        echo isset($this->i) ? "yes " : "no ";
    }
}

$test = new test(array('i' => 'testing'));

//test i while inside the class using $this (returns no)
$test->test_i();

//test i outside of the class using $test (returns no)
echo isset($test->i) ? "yes " : "no ";

//set i to another variable (returns yes)
$ii = $test->i;
echo isset($ii) ? "yes " : "no ";

//returns testing
echo $test->i;

//prints: no no yes testing
?>
```

What I eventually want to do in my HTML file is this:

```
<?=isset($this->var) ? $this->var : ''?>
```

This returns `''` every time. If I `echo $this->var` directly afterward it will display the correct value of var.

Why does this always return false?
Does it have something to do with the magic getter method?
Is it because the `i` variable isn't set directly like `private i;`?

**UPDATE**: It is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306979/will-isset-trigger-get-and-why). Adding the magic isset method fixed it:

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    return $this->args[$name];
}
```

Comment: why dont you use isset inside __get method

Comment: "Is it because the i variable isn't set directly like private i;?".  Yes.  Maybe take your code a bit further and look at [ArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) of SPL.  Can write a more featured class along the lines of what you have now, but allowing things like `offsetExists`, plus all the benefits of it implementing ArrayIterator..

Comment: shouldn't the call in the test_i() function be isset($this->args) rather than $test->i?

Comment: @user829323 no, it shouldn't, __get is being tested here

Comment: I will check that out Mathieu. Looks like it could definitely be the problem. I can try that as well, GGio, thanks.

Comment: **$this = isset($_POST['$args']) ? $_POST['$args'] : 'sample';?** or what or what do you mean?

Comment: No, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `__get`ter is only invoked when you try to access the non-existing property *from outside the class*. Inside the class it is not invoked automatically since your class is supposed to know about its own properties.

Comment: however with isset(), I don't think __get is invoked even outside the class -- __isset is.